# Codeigniter: Accessing a array in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am completely new in the codigniter i just started day befire Yesterday  i am having a problem 
Here is my snippet of my controller code

```
        $allcalldetails_array = array(
                        'id' => $row->id,
                        'customer_id' => $row->customer_id
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata('logged',$allcalldetails_array);
```

I want to iterate the `$allcalldetails_array`  in my views please tell me the way to do this

i tried iterating `logged`  but could not get anything .

If i am printing the array in my views like `print_r($allcalldetails_array);`  but this is also disappointing me .Please help me to get back on track .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not necessary for session variables to be parsed via controller, access it on view directly:

```
$logged = $this->session->userdata('logged');
print_r($logged);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data from session your need to do the following:

```
// controller logic
$logged = $data['logged_for_view'] = $this->session->userdata('logged'); // since 'logged' is the name you set it to
// more controller logic
$this->load->view('view_name', $data);

// in view
var_dump($logged_for_view); // this is the key of the $data variable you assigned for the view
```

Comment: could your elaborate it more

Comment: added a more detailed explanation

Comment: actually i am redirecting on different page instead of loading view

Comment: so what's the problem? You can place this code anywhere you want. You can also use the `$logged` variable I added.

Comment: Your `$logged` variable here isn't used anywhere.

Comment: I know, I set it so he can use it in other places as well, and delete what he doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like data to be send to your view as variables, you should add the corresponding data to your view load.
Controller:

```
$logged = $this->session->userdata('logged');
$this->load->view('viewfile', $logged);
```

View

```
print "logged id:".$id;
```

best regards. 
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [CodeIgniter's documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) :

> Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or
>   an object in the second parameter of the view loading function.

Then you could use something like :

```
// Controller side

$data['allcalldetails_array'] = array(
    'id' => $row->id,
    'customer_id' => $row->customer_id
);
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);


// View side

print_r($allcalldetails_array);

// Loop through your array
foreach ($allcalldetails_array as $detail){
    // Do something with your $detail.
}
```